# Passing always two characters to string from an int value

Tags: android

This is the piece of code i am using to extract:

-day of week

-day of month

-month

-year

-hour

-minutes

from a string

```
//calculo de fechas

         String fecha = resultp.get(Agenda_MainActivity.DIA);//format->2014-04-21
         String time = resultp.get(Agenda_MainActivity.HORA);//format -> 17:30:00
         String string = fecha+" "+time;


            Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
            try {
                calender.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d k:m:s").parse(string));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

All is working fine. The only issue I have is calculating the minutes. This is the code I use to extract the minutes:

```
String Minutos = String.valueOf(calender.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

The problem is the following, if the time is 17:35, then Minutos = "35", as it should be.
But is the time is like 17:00, then Minutos = "0", and not "00".

I need your help to solve this small issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String minute;

String Minutos = String.valueOf(calender.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
if(Integer.parseInt(Minutos)<10){
 minute= "0"+String.valueOf(Minutos)
}
else{
minute = Minutos
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do a simple check for whether the value is less than 10 (a single digit number). If true, prefix the value with a `"0"`.

```
int minutesValue = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
String Minutos = ((minutesValue < 10) ? "0" : "") + String.valueOf(minutesValue);
```